# Build the parent jar with the two child

Tags: spring, maven, plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

I try to build the parent project and the parent project has the two child project i wat get one jar for whole project it should has the whole source code

I have used modules it only build child jar separately

Any idea or example pom.xml
Thanks in advance

Comment: For what purpose?